# Sharepoint 2013 c# customise field data depending on user connected properties

Tags: splist, spuser

I have some specific need here, and i don't know how to approach it. I explain :

I have a SharePoint list to which i am adding a field in feature activated event reciever.
I am adding a 3 choices field.

My problem now is that i want to change the choices depending on the connected user, for example, if the user is a director the choices will be "1","2" and "3" and if the user is an emplyee the choices would be "A", "B" and "C".

Since i am doing this in feature activated event reciever it will always detect the user who is deploying (from VS) not the connected one after...

what is the appropriate event reciever here that will allow me to do this customization?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From what it seems, the only use of event receiver as I see here is creating the field options. There is no way SharePoint allow to display different values based on the person in a choice column.

1. You can create a custom form (visual webpart or InfoPath) and then add all 6 options to the column and display only 3 based on the logged in user.
2. Replace the choice column with a lookup and in the lookup list, set permissions to the items to the directors and employees. There will be 6 list items in the lookup list. Directors will have access to 3 and employees will have access to 3. So then the lookup will show the 3 items appropriately even in the OOTB form.

Comment: How do i attach this new custom form to my list ? knowing that i am using sharepoint list (Discussion Board)

Comment: Please follow this article if you are to use InfoPath. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-HA101821257.aspx Else create a webpart.